# use a system parameter as a color rgba code for style tag in odoo report pdf

Tags: parameters, styles, odoo, qweb, odoo-15

I use Odoo 15, here is my problem, I have set at a record xml file this system parameter, first I try with a rgb code and after that with an hexadecimal code

```xml
    <odoo>
      <data noupdate="0">
        <record id="paleta_color1" model="ir.config_parameter">
          <field name="key">paleta_color1</field>
          <field name="value">#025aa4</field>
        </record>
      </data>
    <odoo>
```

on the other side I made a report. in that report I take the value of my system parameter.

```xml
<t t-set="col" t-value="env['ir.config_parameter'].get_param('paleta_color1', '')" />
```

I can't use a `<t t-esc=col= />` at inline style tag so I have to use a general style tag like this one

```xml
    <style>
             .color {
                 color:<t t-esc="col" />;
             }
             .fondo {
                 border-left : 2px solid <t t-esc="col" />;
             }
             .fond {
                 background-color: <t t-esc="col" />;
             }
    </style>
```

well, manifest is ok, so I tried and nothing happened but I understand the code is fine because it works in html view but not in pdf view. So the problem is about how to get this record styles works in pdf print.

I try to use a system parameter inside a style tag in an Odoo report but this only work in an html view not in pdf print view.

Comment: You can check the [invoice report](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/account/views/report_invoice.xml#L77) to see how Odoo uses variables to set classes

Answer (score 0):

I finally use these two variables from odoo `company.primary_color` and `company.secondary_color` like this:

`t-att-style="'color: %s  !important ;' % company.primary_color"`

I think this was a problem with SCSS internal language of odoo, but I really don't know

anyway, thanks everybody